# MSBuild Error: Reading build config file results in cordova-build error : TypeError: undefined is not a function -Android

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I ran in to this problem while performing Apache cordova build through visual studio-2015 i get this following error.

- VS2015;
- npm -v - 5.7.1
- Node -v 8.8.0
- Cordova tools 6.5.0
- Android project created with cordova-android@6.4.0

Last few lines of error log

```
>  Prepared android project successfully
>  No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
>  Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
>  ------ Copied C:\Project\Mobile\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
>  ------ Building platform: android
>  Debug
>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
>  No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
>  Reading build config file: C:\Project\Mobile\build.json
> MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: undefined is not a function
>  TypeError undefined is not a function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think is node version related issue.

After a few try to build with **VS Cordova Tools** and latest version of **Cordova**, i have encountred some issues on latest node versions.

Try to downgrade node to **Node 4.8.7 LTS**

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.8.7/